# AWS SDK Integration in iOS application

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, sdk, aws-sdk

Any one has integrated AWSPersistance Framework or Dynamic DB Framework in iOS App? I wanted to know how it is used and when can we use these frameworks in iOS App. I have tried using AWS S3 framework and AWSRuntime framework.

I am not finding a good link where in we can see the step wise integration of Dynamic DB and Persistence framework. I downloaded the iOS AWS SDK from  link :https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios-v2.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Neeku, as i described i have already tried using AWS S3 framework and AWSRuntime framework. I followed the samples form https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/ link and kindly vote up for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [AWS Mobile SDK for iOS v2](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios) does not have `AWSPersistance` framework. It has a new `AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper`. You can take a look at a sample [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples) to get started with the object mapper.

Comment: Thank you yosuke . I want to store some files locally in iOS app using core data model. Will it possible using Awsdynamodbobjectmapper or do I need to go with my own xcdatamodel and create required entities or tables and relationship? Also I had another question regarding the S3 framework that is : is it possible to upload or download a file when app is running in the background ? Or can I make use if NSURlsession of Apple iOS Sdk to upload or download a file to S3 in background ?

Comment: The sample link is broken. Please help me, I am also stuck in the same issue. How can I integrate core data with AWS DynamoDB sdk 2.1?